# jquery mobile - select, deselect all select menu options by clicking on "ALL" option

Tags: jquery-mobile, select-menu, jquery-ui-selectmenu

Here is my problem: I use Jquery mobile to style some form elements. One of the form elements is a multiple select menu. I want this select menu to have this behavior http://jsfiddle.net/LynCV/ (this jsfiddle example is not mine i found it on internet). I can achieve this behavior on a native select menu styling, but it doesn't work on a custom menu styling.

here is the code that doesn't do what i want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>select-deselect all</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    /* this jquery script is from the jsfiddle and it is working on native styling but not on a custom styling.*/
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('select').change(function(){
                if (this.selectedIndex == 0){
                    $('option:gt(0)', this).prop('selected',false);
                }else{
                    $('option:first', this).prop('selected',false);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <label for="selectBox">Choose one or more</label>
    <select id="selectBox" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">//select element in note a native menu but custom you can see it by data-native-menu="false"
        <option value="all">all</option>
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="tow">tow</option>
        <option value="three">three</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

again what i want is: when selecting "ALL" option to deselect all the other options and don't allow to select any other option without deselecting "ALL" option. When deselect "ALL" option allow to select one or more options.

edit1: reading the jquery mobile API. I sow here http://api.jquerymobile.com/select/#method-refresh that to achieve what i want i have to use refresh() method. But i couldn't understand how to use it.

edit2:My question here maybe considered as duplicated, but I searched for answers and I couldn't understand how to use the solutions that I found for solving my problem. So I am asking for a specific answer to my problem.

edit2: as you can see I am a beginner to all of this.

thank you for you time and possible answers. Please if is possible provide me some code example. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your case just call

```
$("#selectBox").selectmenu("refresh");
```

after you have changed the "selected" property.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select').change(function(){
            if (this.selectedIndex == 0){
                $('option:gt(0)', this).prop('selected',false);
            }else{
                $('option:first', this).prop('selected',false);
            }
            $("#selectBox").selectmenu("refresh");
        });
    });
```